# Replacing all values greater than a value of a specific column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried several versions but all of them throw a warning, starting with:

```
colName = 'age'    
df_plot[colName][df_plot[colName]>10] = 10
```

> ```
>  SettingWithCopyWarning: 
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. See the caveats in the documentation:
> ```
>
> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Based on the link from the warning then:

```
df_plot.loc[:, (colName, df_plot[colName]>10)] = 10
```

> ```
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
> ```

Next

```
df_plot.loc[colName, df_plot[colName] > 10] = 10
```

> ```
> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
> ```

And finally based on a stack-overflow answer also:

```
df_plot[colName] = df_plot[colName].apply(lambda x: [y if y <= 10 else 10 for y in x])


TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `df_plot.loc[df_plot[colName]>10, colName] = 10` ?

Comment: First option doesn't even throw any warnings for me.

Comment: Concerning the last option: if you drop the list comprehension, it should work fine, i.e.: `df_plot[colName] = df_plot[colName].apply(lambda x: x if x <= 10 else 10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easier way to [**`clip`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) values:

```
df_plot[colName] = df_plot[colName].clip(upper=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt seems correct to me, and works without warnings on my machine.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':range(5,15), 'size':range(10)})
colName = 'age'
df[colName][df[colName]>10] = 10
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   age  size
0    5     0
1    6     1
2    7     2
3    8     3
4    9     4
5   10     5
6   10     6
7   10     7
8   10     8
9   10     9
```

Comment: Interesting, your minimal version works on my system without warning but why does it throw a warning with my "real" data frame ...? EDIT: My column is of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> - very strange (it's an import from a SQL DB)

Comment: @lordy: The warning occurs only in case `df_plot` is already a copy of a slice. This depends on how `df_plot` is defined. Maybe, before your posted commands, you slice another `DataFrame` for example by using some command like this: `df_plot = df_original[['age', 'height', 'weight']]`. Then the warning is raise. If instead you do `df_plot = df_original[['age', 'height', 'weight']].copy()` the warning will disappear.

Comment: @brexi: you are right - I am doing that as I select only a subset of columns for plotting but the .copy() does not remove the warning ...

Comment: that is bizarre. Could you maybe post a few more lines of code leading up to what you already posted?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `numpy.where()`? Let me use @Zvika's sample df.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'age':range(5,15), 'size':range(10)})
>>> df
   age  size
0    5     0
1    6     1
2    7     2
3    8     3
4    9     4
5   10     5
6   11     6
7   12     7
8   13     8
9   14     9

>>> df['age'] = np.where(df['age']>10, [10],df['age'])
>>> df
   age  size
0    5     0
1    6     1
2    7     2
3    8     3
4    9     4
5   10     5
6   10     6
7   10     7
8   10     8
9   10     9
```